# Is there a way to capture a name from the environment when using hy.eval?

Tags: hy

I'm trying to create functions in hylang and use them from python but the created functions don't seem to have access to the environment passed to hy.eval.

```
import hy

env = dict(x=5)
func = hy.eval(hy.read_str('(fn [] x)'), env)
print(func())
```

The call to `func` results in `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. I also tried

```
hy.eval(hy.read_str('(func)'), env)
```

without luck (same error). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hy.eval` doesn't have a `globals` parameter but it has a `module` parameter and by looking at the source I found that `module.__dict__` is passed as `globals` to `eval`. So the following works:

```
import hy
from types import ModuleType

env = dict(x=5)
module = ModuleType('<string>')
module.__dict__.update(env)
func = hy.eval(hy.read_str('(fn [] x)'), module=module)
print(func())
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `hy.eval` is `locals`, not `globals` as for Python's `eval`. Implicitly using the calling environment works fine, though, so you can write this more straightforwardly as

```
 import hy

 x = 5
 func = hy.eval(hy.read_str('(fn [] x)'))
 print(func())
```

Comment: What would it take to implement globals? My problem with using the calling environment is that 1) the env I want to pass is big 2) the env changes dynamically 3) the same env is reused by multiple hy.eval calls in different places and 4) the created function is stored and called later from somewhere else.

Comment: Would x be captured if it was marked as nonlocal in the fn?

Comment: @Kris Making a module object, as in your own answer, is probably the easiest way to get this as `hy.eval` is currently implemented.